# Set Trace of GAE Web App Handler Function

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am used to using the following paradigm for setting and ending a trace of a python function:

```
sys.settrace(traceFunction)
someFunction()
sys.settrace(None)
```

This model seems to fail if someFunction() is a function (e.g. post()) defined in a handler in the production of a web app through google app engine.  Because said function is never instantiated specifically in the code, I am unsure as to how to set a trace on it.  Can anyone tell me of a method that would achieve the same result as the above model in this context?

Comment: what exactly do you want to trace? It might be easier to use a decorator instead...

Comment: I am trying to use the trace as a part of a debugger I'm building.  This debugger will ideally do several things including tracking the ranges of local variables to assist with producing assertions (like the tool Daikon does) and track the number of times each line is read .  I am by no means an experienced programmer and am not sure how I would produce a trace using a decorator.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: for that end, you would definitely need to use sys.settrace! You might want to add some more information to your question about what you are looking for and how traceFunction is defined. (it's not 100% clear from your question)

Comment: traceFunction is relatively simple.  All I need it to be able to do is to collect the values of local variables, the line number, and the name of the function currently being executed (through some means comparable to frame.f_locals, frame.f_lineno, and frame.f_code.co_name respectively).  I can get these values from something like inspect.currentframe(), but this would make producing the kind of debugger I want much more difficult than having a trace would.